# Facing issues while implementing graceful shutdown feature

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am working on standalone spring boot application and used spring integration channel architecture to transfer files from source to destination.
We have provided multi-instance feature as well, to achieve this we will be locking(append .lock for the files) files for particular instance to restrict access from other instance.
Currently, I have one requirement for graceful shutdown . I implemented but end-up with the following error. Can anyone help me on this ?

```
Control bus configuration :

<integration:channel id="controlChannel" />
<integration:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel" />

Adapter configuration :

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInChannel"
        directory="path" auto-startup="false" scanner="recursiveScanner"
        auto-create-directory="true">
        <integration:poller id="poller"
            max-messages-per-poll="5" fixed-rate="1000" 
            task-executor="pollingExecutor">
            <integration:transactional
                transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        </integration:poller>
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

Method added for graceful shutdown component
@PreDestroy
    public void onDestroy() throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            inboundFileAdapterChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop()"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // wait till current processing of files is over
        pollingExecutor.shutdown();
        pollingExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(Boolean.TRUE);
        System.out.println("Application shutdown succesfully");
    }
```

Error Trace :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.controlChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop(), headers={id=5f0282c5-5a02-3f57-3056-948dd74a8d72, timestamp=1559894703464}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop(), headers={id=5f0282c5-5a02-3f57-3056-948dd74a8d72, timestamp=1559894703464}]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
        at com.openbank.interfaces.file.handler.GracefulShutdownHook.onDestroy(GracefulShutdownHook.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:577)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:549)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop(), headers={id=5f0282c5-5a02-3f57-3056-948dd74a8d72, timestamp=1559894703464}]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Why do you have `spring-integration-aws` tag if there is nothing about AWS in your question? Please, be careful when you chose tags for questions. It's is hard to give you answer when we don't see enough info or provided one is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

`@PreDestroy` is too late to perform such operations.

By that time all `Lifecyle` beans will have been `stop()`ped (which unsubscribes from the channel).

You need to perform that work using some other signal.

You could implement `SmartLifecyle` and put your bean in a late phase (so it is `stop()`ped early.